# Proof of NP-completeness of a special case of longest-path problem

Tags: np-complete, proof-techniques

**Problem**: **Longest Path**

**Input**: An undirected graph $G=(V,E)$

**Question**: Is there a path of length at least $\frac{|V|}4$?

I know that in order to prove the simple version of $k$ longest path, we reduce the Hamiltonian path to longest path. How we can prove the $NP$-completeness in this special case? Should I use a reduction from Hamiltonian cycle?

**Edit**: A hint : Reduction from Hamiltonian path. Try to think how many vertices should be added to a special instance $G'$ of Longest path problem so that if there is a path least $\frac{|V|}{4}$ vertices in length then there is a Hamiltonian path in $G$.

Comment: Hint: what if the graph is not connected?

Comment: sorry ,i should have mentioned that $G$ is connected. The only hint i know is that i should consider a new graph which contains extra nodes.

Comment: You can easily prove that it is NP-complete using a reduction from Hamiltonian $s-t$ path. Just add enough nodes and link ....

Comment: @Vor You can even more easily prove that it is **NP**-complete using a reduction from the usual "Is there a path of length at least $k$" version of longest path.

Comment: @Vor Can you be more specific please? i haven't solve something similar so i don't know how should i approach the problem.(or suggest a book/source so i can read about similar reductions)

Comment: @David Richerby So it correct to say that this problem is np complete because is a special case of the k longest path which we can prove to be np complete using reduction from hamiltonian path?

Comment: @hardstudent Being a special case of a hard problem is not enough to prove hardness: hard problems can have easy special cases (e.g., 3-colourability is easy on bipartite graphs). You need to reduce $k$-longest path to the special case. That is, given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k$, produce a graph $G'=(V',E')$ such that $G'$ contains a path of length at least $|V'|/4$ if, and only if, $G$ contains a path of length at least $k$.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that requiring the graph $G$ to be connected does not decrease the hardness of our problem here.

Reduce from **Hamiltonian path** between $2$ **specified vertices**, namely $s,t\in V(G)$

Like before, we want to add new vertices to the graph while keeping it connected.

Now, **do some arithmetics**:

A Hamiltonian path between $s$ and $t$ is of length $n-1$, where $n=|V|$

If we attach some paths of length (at most) $k$ to $s$ and $t$, then we can increase the length of a path up to $n-1+2k$.

We should have $4(n-1+2k)=|\mathcal{V}|$ in the new graph $\mathcal{G(V,E)}$.

So $|\mathcal{V}|-|V|=3n-4+8k$. Take $k=\sqrt{n}$. Alternatively, attach $s$ and then $t$ and again $s$, etc. to a new **short** path of length (at most) $k$ (i.e. $k$ new vertices).

The point of setting $k=\sqrt{n}$ is to prevent one from concatenating $2$ **short** paths attached to the same vertex (either $s$ or $t$). So, one must take one path attached to each vertex among $s$ and $t$. And the **middle part** of the path is a Hamiltonian path between $s$ and $t$.